# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found:

Tags: java, mariadb, java-ee-7, tomee-7

After having gotten a servlet with a JDBC datasource working fine, I am now trying to wire up a JPA configuration. In doing so I have paged through hundreds of posts and manuals, and tried different things, and every time it all comes back to the same exception mentioned in the subject:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MUSICIAN

As mentioned I have tried multiple different configurations, but here is what I have currently.   I have two different servlets.  I will describe the first because I get the same error on the second so same issue.

Oh - TomEE Plume 7.0.2, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_181, MariaDB 10.3.8.

First, my Musician class:

```
package gym;

...imports omitted for brevity...

@Entity
@Table(name="musician")
public class Musician {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="musician_id")
    private int musician_id;

    @Column(name="namelast")
    private String namelast;

    @Column(name="namefirst")
    private String namefirst;

    @Column(name="biography")
    private String biography;

    @Column(name="nickname")
    private String nickname;

    public Musician() {
    }
    ... getters/setters omitted for brevity...
}
```

Here is the servlet code:

```
package gym;

... imports left out for brevity...

public class GymJPAServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceContext(name="gymPU",unitName="gymPU")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        StringBuilder es = new StringBuilder();

        es.append("Entity Manager Stuff: " + em.toString() + "<br/><br/>");
        es.append("Entity Manager Contains: " + em.contains(gym.Musician.class) + "<br/><br/>");
        Set entities = em.getMetamodel().getEntities();
        es.append("Entities: " + entities + "<br/><br/>");

        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Musician m = em.find(Musician.class, 1);
            es.append("found it : " + m + "<br/><br/>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ... nonessential exception handling code omitted for brevity
        }
        if (results != null) {
            for (Iterator i = results.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                Musician m = (Musician)(i.next());
                es.append("musician: " + m.toString() + "<br/><br/>");
            }
        } else {
            es.append(es.toString());
        }

        out.write("<html><head></head><body>\n");
        out.write(es.toString());
        out.write("</body></html>\n");

    }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

  <persistence-unit name="gymPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/GymDS</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/Gym</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>gym.Musician</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

my WEB-INF/resources.xml:

```
<Resource id="jdbc/GymDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed = false
    alternateUsernameAllowed = false
    defaultAutoCommit = true
    ignoreDefaultValues = false
    initialSize = 0
    jdbcDriver = org.mariadb.jdcbc.Driver
    jdbcUrl = jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/gym
    jtaManaged = true
    maxActive = 20
    maxIdle = 20
    maxOpenPreparedStatements = 0
    maxWaitTime = 10000
    minEvictableIdleTime = 30 minutes
    minIdle = 0
    numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
    password = mypassword
    passwordCipher = PlainText
    poolPreparedStatements = false
    testOnBorrow = true
    testOnReturn = false
    testWhileIdle = false
    timeBetweenEvictionRuns = -1 millisecond
    userName = gymadmin
</Resource>
```

And finally, my context.xml for reference for the non-jta ds:

```
<Context>
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/Gym"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWaitMillis="10000"
    username="gymadmin" password="mypassword"
    driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/gym"/>
</Context>
```

So on the other end is the MariaDB instance.   I am able to connect to it just fine using straight JDBC with no JPA, from servlets in the same container.  This is important because I feel this all adds up to the fact that something is not wired right in my JPA setup, and so the "object not found" is that it cannot find it in the internal JPA setup rather than in the db on the other end. This is reinforced to me by clues from the TomEE log.

The other servlet I tried creating a separate MusicianDAO stateless bean, but it gives me the same exception. So I will not belabor this post by showing the second servlet code unless necessary later on.

Here are the clues from my tomee log. When deploying the app, I get:

> 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.727 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication
>   Configuring enterprise application:
>   /home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.917
>   INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService
>   Configuring Service(id=gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym, type=Resource,
>   provider-id=ProvidedByTomcat) 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.919 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating
>   Resource(id=gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym) 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.924 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking
>   resource-ref 'jdbc/Gym' in bean gym-0.1.1-dev.Comp1022583414 to
>   Resource(id=jdbc/Gym) 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.925 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking
>   resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym' in bean
>   gym-0.1.1-dev.Comp1022583414 to Resource(id=gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym)
>   19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.925 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking
>   resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/jdbc/Gym' in bean
>   gym-0.1.1-dev.Comp1022583414 to Resource(id=gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym)
>   19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.925 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Configuring
>   PersistenceUnit(name=gymPU) 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.926 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy
>   Found matching datasource: gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym but this one is a
>   JTA datasource 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.926 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy
>   Found matching datasource: gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym but this one is a
>   JTA datasource 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.926 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy
>   Found matching datasource: gym-0.1.1-dev/jdbc/Gym but this one is a
>   JTA datasource
>   **19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.927 INFO [localhost-startStop-13] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setJtaDataSource Adjusting
>   PersistenceUnit gymPU  to Resource ID 'Default JDBC
>   Database' from 'jdbc/GymDS' 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.931 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setNonJtaDataSource Adjusting
>   PersistenceUnit gymPU  to Resource ID 'Default
>   Unmanaged JDBC Database' from 'jdbc/Gym'** 19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.936
>   INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application
>   "/home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev" loaded. 19-Mar-2019
>   15:42:15.937 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication
>   Assembling app: /home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev
>   19-Mar-2019 15:42:15.975 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate
>   PersistenceUnit(name=gymPU,
>   provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) - provider
>   time 29ms 19-Mar-2019 15:42:16.043 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using
>   context file
>   /home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev/META-INF/context.xml
>   19-Mar-2019 15:42:16.046 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication
>   Deployed
>   Application(path=/home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev)
>   19-Mar-2019 15:42:16.308 INFO [localhost-startStop-13]
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web
>   application archive /home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev.war
>   has finished in 839 ms [EL Info]: 2019-03-19
>   15:43:47.421--ServerSession(1356468468)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5
>   **[EL Info]: 2019-03-19 15:43:47.499--ServerSession(1356468468)--/file:/home/omadmin/tomeeapps/webapps/gym-0.1.1-dev/_gymPU
>   login successful [EL Warning]: 2019-03-19
>   15:43:47.506--ServerSession(1356468468)--Problem while registering
>   MBean: java.lang.NullPointerException [EL Warning]: 2019-03-19
>   15:43:47.51--UnitOfWork(570034438)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or
>   object not found: MUSICIAN Error Code: -5501** Call: SELECT
>   musician_id, biography, namefirst, namelast, nickname FROM musician
>   WHERE (musician_id = ?)   bind => [1 parameter bound] Query:
>   ReadObjectQuery(name="readMusician" referenceClass=Musician
>   sql="SELECT musician_id, biography, namefirst, namelast, nickname FROM
>   musician WHERE (musician_id = ?)")

So.. being a complete JEE noob here, the best I can come up with is that it appears to me I still don't have something wired right in the config files, and so because of that, it does away with my **gymDS** data source and replaces it with some default internal db representation, and then when the database call is made, well *of course* it cant find the MUSICIAN object in this alternate reality version of a database "Default JDBC database" as seen in the log snippet above.

The "file:... login successful" thing is suspicious too but I suspect that's a side effect of the previously mentioned issue.

NOTE also I have not done anything with the global tomee.xml because I was trying to do this local to the app and not global.  I mention this because some things I read seem to indicate I may need to touch that file anyway but I am not to that point yet.

Anyway I don't know what else to try. I have not tried a different container yet but maybe I need to spin all this up under a different JEE system such as OpenLiberty to see if the same thing happens.

In the mean time, can anyone shed any light?  It's got to be something simple, a field I am missing here or there or perhaps my persistence.xml is in the wrong location, something...???

Comment: Well do you have a table MUSICIAN in the database and if so what are the access rights for the user account you are using?

Comment: Yes.  I apologize I did not spell that out explicityly in the beginning, of the post, but that is what I was getting at when I said I had it working via straight JDBC.  But yes, I can work with the database just fine using JDBC against this database.  So it does have a table "musician" and I have verified the gymadmin userid/password works via JDBC and produces query results, which is all I am doing at the moment til I get this working.